# Conditional Formatting with split string and wildcard

Tags: google-sheets, split, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

I have a database from A4:AV for different strings.

DATA SET
|Data|
|12AB34 Toyota|
|12CD34 Ford|
|12AB56 Hyundai|
|78CD90 Kia|
|78EF90 Benz|

I would like to write a conditional formatting code that highlights if 1st/2nd/5th/6th character happen more than once.

For example if in A4 there is "12AB34 Toyota", and in A5 "12CD34 Ford" they would both highlight as both A4 and A5 have XX??YY twice (12--34). The same for "78CD90 Kia" and "78EF90 Benz" as they both have XX??YY twice (78--90).

I've tried using this formula for column A4:A first:
 `=SUMPRODUCT((LEN(A4:A)>5)*((MID(A4:A,1,1)&MID(A4:A,2,1)&MID(A4:A,5,1)&MID(A4:A,6,1))=REGEXREPLACE(A4:A,"(.)\\1{1}","$1")))>0`

But I cannot get it to work, if you can help that would be a massive help!

Here is a sheet of desired outcomes [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UOnqnZ_xMeUttqg2ogANpfB_hdw1nLnNnQ8Yv_nFEkU/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this `custom formula` in CF

```
=(len(A4)>5)*(index(countifs(mid($A$4:$Z,1,2),mid(A4,1,2),mid($A$4:$Z,5,2),mid(A4,5,2)))>1)
```

[image]

Comment: It is not working, it only works for 12AB34/12CD34 but not 78CD90 and 78EF90.

Comment: Whats the `data range` you selected within `Apply to range` setting in conditional formatting rules? It should start from `A4` onwards...

Comment: I have done so, you can see on the example sheet, on sheet named rockinfreakshow. I have also applied this to the bigger data base of A4:AV99 and everything is colored in

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/AXZUW73.png you applied the range from `A1` itself when the formula starts from `A4` and so on... so you can see yellow format color shifted 3 rows upwards.